# do_octave_atexit missing? does createOctaveComponent work?

Tags: redhawksdr

I made a short .m file

```
function myOutput = multiplyByConstant(myInput, myConstant=1)
    myOutput = myInput * myConstant;
```

And then used the provided *createOctaveComponent* command to make it into a .. thing

I go into the generated folder and try to run build.sh, but the build won't work.

multiplyByConstant_base.cpp:69:22: error: 'do_octave_atexit' was not declared at this scope.

I tried running grep over all the .h files I though that would matter, but the method was not exported anywhere.

I found a post here: http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/exposing-do-octave-atexit-in-the-API-td4661829.html

They discuss about exposing said method.

Have I missed some crucial step? Can I replace do_octave_atexit with something else?

---

EDIT:
I'm using:

- Ocateve 3.8.2
- REDHAWK 2.0.4

Comment: What version of Octave are you using? Octave changes its API from time-to-time, and the method in question might not be supported in the version you are using. Ironically, you might need to downgrade Octave (that method might have been removed or renamed in newer versions).

Comment: I guess that's it, it was present in older versions. Any idea what version of Octave I should use to prevent issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: This compatibility issue has been resolved in REDHAWK 2.0.6 and REDHAWK 2.1.0. You will need to regenerate your component for the change to take effect.

It definitely sounds like downgrading Octave will get you up and running for older REDHAWK versions. The code generators in REDHAWK 1.10.0-2.0.5 are compatible with Octave 3.4.3-3.6.4 (I don't recall exactly when the break happened, but I remember it being in a sub-minor release after 3.6.4). 3.4.3 is what ships with CentOS 6. This is a known compatibility issue with REDHAWK <= 2.0.5 and the version of Octave that ships with CentOS 7.

Comment: Can you look at this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592967/error-registering-gpp-device-on-a-domain

Comment: At the time of this writing, REDHAWK 2.0.6 and 2.1.0 are not yet available. They can be built from the develop-2.0 and develop-2.1 branches in the meantime (this applies for future not-yet-released versions as well).