# Error registering GPP device on a domain

Tags: redhawksdr

I am using REDHAWK 2.0.5, and I am attempting to launch a domain using the instructions in section '11.1.1 Launching a Domain' of the REDHAWK documentation:
https://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch11.html#x13-30800011.2

I receive the following error after clicking OK in step 3 when attempting to register the GPP device on the Domain Manager:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost:exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_lexical_cast> >'
  what():  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
```

Does anyone have experience with this issue?  Or, any suggestions about what the cause might be?

Comment: I have the same issue. I have set REDHAWK up previously but I cannot remember running into this issue, several others, but not this.

Comment: I get this error on REDHAWK 2.1.0

Comment: Are all of these completely clean installs or systems with older versions of REDHAWK/Boost that have been yum updated at some point?

Comment: I got this error to go away by calling redhawk.sk and redhawk-sdrroot.sh before starting the IDE. The new one is a completely clean install, starting from the OS.

Comment: However, I cannot run any component in debug mode. Release mode works fine, but any component I have made crashes instantly when I try to run them in debug mode. Even if the component only copies output to input. Release versions work fine, so I can sort of debug them by trying if they crash or not.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be an issue with the version of boost libraries you have installed.  Can you tell me which linux flavor and version you're using, and how you installed the Redhawk framework itself?

Comment: I have the same problem with 2.1.0 REDHAWK. I used CentOS 7 64 bit. I installed REDHAWK by downloading the YUM archive and installing from the repository. I have boost version 1.53.0-26, the 64 bit version one.

Comment: The interesting thing is that I have 2.0.1 REDHAWK installed on another machine and there it works. Both machines have the same CentOS version installed from the same disc and boost installed from the same repository.